# Ellipse and parallel lines

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Let's imagine that we have an **ellipse** described by the known equation $v^TAv=0$, [(Link_1)](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/geometry/simple.html)  where $v=[x \ y \ 1]^T$
(it can be a skew one in a general case).
Then we have **all possible parallel lines** - for example  horizontal  lines on the $OXY$  plane:  $y=b$.   Some of these lines don't cross ellipse, two are tangent to ellipse at points $C_1$ and $C_2$,  other cross it in two points $B_1$ and $B_2$.

**Question:**
Is there a relatively easy proof that  **midpoints** of all segments $B_1B_2$ (preferable way to start from the mentioned above general equation) construct linear segment $C_1C_2$ and the midpoint of this segment $C_1C_2$ is the center of ellipse ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Well...*relatively* easy if you're willing to allow me to use Sylvester's law of inertia, which says that every symmetric matrix over the reals is diagonalizable.

The matrix $A$ can be replaced by $(A + A^t)/2$ without changing the ellipse, so we may assume $A$ is symmetric.

Write $A = Q^t D Q$ for some orthogonal matrix $Q$ and diagonal matrix $D$. Under the transformation $v \mapsto \sqrt{D}Qv$, the ellipse $A$ gets mapped to the unit circle. (The matrix $D$ has a square root because your quadratic form determines an ellipse, i.e., both eigenvalues are positive.)

Under that same transformation, which involves only rotation (by $Q$) and scaling along the axes (by $\sqrt{D}$), the set of horizontal chords of the ellipse is transformed into a set of parallel chords of the circle, and the midpoint operation is preserved.

In the new coordinate system, the midpoints of a set of parallel chords of a circle form a segment that's a diameter of the circle... and we're done: we transform that segment back to get a straight segment in the original space, and its midpoint is still the center of the ellipse.

(To make all this work really cleanly, it helps to begin by translating the ellipse to have its center at the origin.)

**A post-comment note:** Suppose that $T$ is linear. I claim that for a segment $AB$, the midpoint of $AB$ transforms, under $T$, to the midpoint of the segment from $T(A)$ to $T(B)$.

Proof: The midpoint $M$ is just $0.5A + 0.5B$. When we apply $T$, we get
\begin{align}
T(M) &= T(0.5A + 0.5B) \\
&= T(0.5A) + T(0.5B) \\
&= 0.5 T(A) + 09.5 T(B)
\end{align}
which is the midpoint of the segment between $T(A)$ and $T(B)$.

Comment: @ John Hmm, midpoints for chords in circle mean midpoints for a chords in ellipse ? I don't see where you used the equation.. D is orthogonal ?

Comment: See post-comment addition to my answer.

Comment: $Q$ is orthogonal. $D$ is diagonal. What equation did I not use?

Comment: @Wida, note that an ellipse is merely an affine transformation of a circle. Then apply that affine transformation to a chord of that circle and its midpoint...

Comment: BTW, my proof shows that the same claim about midpoints of parallel chords hold whether they're parallel to the $x$ axis or to any other line -- I never needed to use the hypothesis that the chords were axis-parallel. That turns out to have been a red herring.

Comment: @John You've written in the answer D is orthogonal, so we must correct it. And 0.95 :) The proof is amazingly simple. The same, I suppose, can be for vertical lines. Maybe you also could prove additionally that both obtained segments ( from vertical and horizontal lines) cross at the center of ellipse? ( without mentioning midpoints). I'm using this simple procedure in the finding of centers of ellipses in the images and I'm glad that now I have some theoretical support for it. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks...I fixed that by saying that $Q$ is orthogonal and $D$ diagonal, which is what I meant all along, but I typed faster than I thought. :)  Yes, the proof shows that the claim's true for vertical lines (or 45-degree slope lines, or any other pencil of parallel lines). And it does, indeed, show that the segments obtained from vertical and horizontal chord-centers meet at the ellipse center, but I'm not sure how you could talk about those segments without mentioning midpoints. :)

Comment: @0K. All possible segments have midpoints at the center, so they all have to cross at the one point :)

Comment: @John Maybe in geometry it doesn't matter whether parallel lines are horizontal or not, however in image processing it is a difference :)

Comment: Indeed...my point was not that the lines need NOT to be horizontal, but instead that they could be along any direction, so that you could, in your image processing, also use diagonal lines of pixels where $x + y = c$ or $x-y = c$ if those happened to be more convenient.

Comment: @John Ok. However diagonal can miss pixels if it crosses with the other orthogonal diagonal: 1_pixel_wide little fragment of ellipse (horizontal, vertical never).. To ensure a case of hitting a pixel we then additionally have to dilate lines..in discrete world lines are not the same as in the continuous one :) Once again Thank You.

Comment: That happens with horizontal lines, too: the ellipse $10(x-0.5)^2 + 0.01y^2 = 1$ crosses the axis, but in a rasterized version of the ellipse, no pixel on the x-axis will be "inside". If you don't confidently know which pixels are within your ellipse, you shouldn't be computing midpoints of segments made of them. (No one is more sensitive than I to the problems of aliasing ... see about 4 chapters of *Computer Graphics: Principles and Practice," 3rd. edition.) BTW, dilating (along the normal direction) the outline of a rotated ellipse will cause the midpoint-finding approach to break.

Comment: @John Rotations of ellipse I was not checking, only translations for binary images scanned from inside. Thank you for the recommendation of your book. I'm sure it is very good.

Comment: Oh... I wasn't recommending it. Just pointing out that having written a whole lot about aliasing, I'm as sensitive to it as the next guy, if not more so. As for rotated ellipses: the ones given by $v^t M v = 0$ may BE rotated in general, so this concern about thickened edges applies to the class of ellipses described in your question. Best of luck!